# NLP short text marking approach

Tags: nlp

I am working on a project to evaluate short answer questions for an educational institution.  Here is what I need to do:

Teacher has a sample answer (known to us in advance).
 Sample answer has 3-4 keywords.
 Student enters the answer.  The application should evaluate student's answer as below:

- Contextual meaning of those keywords should be present in the answer with same/similar relations as in sample answer.
- Students are expected to use the synonyms of the keywords.
- Proper relationships of the synonyms are expected as well.
- Students are not allowed to use the same        keywords (no marks if
  they use the keywords in their answer).
- Answers are not more that 2-3 sentences.

Can someone guide me what is a good approach for this?  Looking for some starting point to accomplish this.  I am familiar with basics of the NLP, but not worked with much tools available there.

Answer (score 1):

There is a sub-discipline of Applied Linguistics called ["computer assisted language learning" (often CALL for short)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-assisted_language_learning) that I'm not too familiar with, but probably has some insights you'd want to leverage. It's more about automatic grading, etc. of, for example, student essays of non-native English speakers, but I suspect you might want to get familiar with CALL research.

This is a really hard problem and not one generally solved. In the end, you'll want a human in the loop---that is, the system assigns grades, and the instructor needs to check off that they agree. Both the NLP isn't good enough and the understanding of language and knowledge isn't clear enough that you can get a full and accurate picture of the meaning of text automatically.

With that caveat in mind, I'd start with getting as many actual examples of teacher answers and correct and incorrect student answers as you possibly can. You'll need to have some kind of gold standard data for two reasons: to understand how well your system is working (evaluation) and to understand what makes a right and wrong answer (insight). Without actual examples, it's unlikely you'll have a working system; with actual examples, it's still going to be hard, but now you know how well you're doing.

As a first pass, instead of doing anything fancy, do [a tf.idf weighted bag-of-words model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model). Use the cosine distance to compare teacher/student answers, and see how well you can predict right or wrong based on the cosine distance. This won't be perfect, of course, but it will give you a good baseline to compare your other results to.

You could try replacing the tf.idf bag of words with some kind of word2vec (W2V) system next. W2V helps solve some issues of synonymy, but you'll need a lot of genre-specific text to make it work properly, and I doubt with this application you'll have enough.

From there, I'd start playing with using a parser and trying to use relationships between the words to get at the intended meaning. That's well down the road, though. Get that data first.